# How to set cursor when its hovering over form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-xp

I would like to set cursor to arrow when its over a form.

I'm using Media Player control and if I move it quickly from outside the form to the control inside of the form it stay as resize cursor. I would like to somehow force the cursor to always be arrow when it enters the form.

How to do it? is it possible?

Comment: You mean if you move it slowly into the control on the form it works fine, i.e. no resize cursor when hovering over the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a cursor property on the media player control, then this should work.

```
        this.mediaPlayer.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.UpArrow;
```